# (sendex face_recognition) Photo reshaping problem in cv2. which will be use as input for Face recognition

Tags: python, face-recognition, opencv

I am following sentdex face recognition [video](https://pythonprogramming.net/facial-recognition-python/). I am using my own pics for training the model which are very large in size so I changed the size of my pics into 256x256 with the help of `cv2.reshape()` here is the code I'm using for resizing. I did it 10 time for 10 pics you can make use of loop for it.

```
import cv2

#paste the path where you have face recognition file
#for me it is '/home/Desktop/ml/face_reco'
path = str(input("paste you file path here: "))

IMG_SIZE = 256

# convert to array
img_array = cv2.imread(path)  

new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) 

#save the resized pic with some new name
cv2.imwrite('/home/Desktop/ml/face_reco/known_faces/vardhan/new.png',new_array)
```

when I use these newly resized pics as the input for the model then it's raising an error `list index out of range` because the `encoding` array is empty in line 38 of sentdex [code](https://pythonprogramming.net/facial-recognition-python/) and I don't know why encoding array is empty for new pics which was not empty for the original pics.